# I want my server to be the only one to access my API, can I use a secret to make sure of that?

Tags: node.js, api, express, networking

so I'm working on an API for user authentication. I want the functions to only be called by another server. I was thinking of checking the origin in the headers but it's not the ideal solution as tools like Postman can compromise that.

Would a solution be to have a secret key inside the header that is checked for in each request? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe issue JWT's to your other server just like you might to a connecting client.

Comment: A very secure and easy way to handle this is to use HTTPS.  You can use client keys and verify those keys.  That way, each end knows who it is talking to, and the correct key is required.

Comment: How about a client-certificate based authentication? https://github.com/julie-ng/nodejs-certificate-auth